# Checkout is not working in opencart 1.5.6.4 after selecting delivery method

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

Here is my store [store.suhaskhamkar.in](http://store.suhaskhamkar.in/) . I'm using opencart 1.5.6.4 for my store, in this when customer do `checkout` it stucks in step #4 i.e. Delivery method. There are some errors on console like `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function`.

Comment: What is `colorbox`?? any plugin??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small mistake in placing the scripts in your code.

First `jquery.colorbox-min.js` then jquery-1.7.1.min.js

This line should come first.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
```

Then this line should come

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry but where should i do these changes?

Comment: where have you included all your script(JS) files??

Comment: I can't understand where it is present

Comment: Check in yor checkout.php file. if not present check in the files you have included.

Comment: Thanks for help, its present in `catalog\view\theme\OPC050107\template\common\header.tpl`